# How to create a table of "Not used time" in spotfire

Tags: data-analysis, spotfire

User wants to see a report of when resources are NOT being used during the work week on average.

Available to me I have a reservations table along these lines:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nw0JU.png)
Attached is the picture of how the user would like the data represented. [example graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs8bn.png)

I think my issue lays in getting the data in the right format, how can I take a reservations table and inverse it so to show all available time in-between two reservations.

I was able to get a Bar graph that showed the average availability of the days that the resource was booked, but it didn't consider days that there was no reservation information, it also did not account for situations where the user had booked for more then one day.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making a calculated column?

This worked for me:

1440 - Sum([Duration]) OVER ([StartDateTime])

1440 is the amount of minutes in a day. It subtracts the total amount of 'busy' time in each day from the total minutes in the day.

It is then easy to make a bar chart from this column.

This worked in my testing, but it might run into issues if you put it into practice. Keep me updated!

[Table with calculated column, and barchart.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98SUJ.png)

Comment: Yes I have tried this, but it doesn't take into account the days when a resource is not used at all.